# How to get contacts API from Dynamics CRM in iOS?

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am working on a mobile application (both iOS and Android in native code). In this there is functionality of login with Dynamics 365 and get contacts from it. In this I have used OAUTH2.0 library to implement login functionality. Login is working fine. Next, I want to fetch contacts from Dynamics 365 using API. So I am following below documentation link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contact?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

In mobile app, I am not getting any response when I call this API. Also there is no error.

When I try to call `[organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/contacts` from my computer browser then it gives me contacts after login. 
Do I need to pass any token/authorizationCode/header parameters etc while calling this API from mobile app? In documentation they didn't mention anything regarding which things I need to pass while calling contact API.

Also I am not sure if I must have to use its mobile SDK to implement this feature rather then normal API call?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [Register an app (CRM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory) with Azure Active Directory.
Here is first link which will help you out.

Using postman you call call webapi follow all the steps in below [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/use-postman-perform-operations?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening the CRM in a browser window, it writes the `Bearer Token` and `Refresh Token` in cookies, which is used by mobile app as well. This cookies ensures the smooth single sign-on.

To achieve this in mobile app, during first time login you have to do the same logic using `ADAL.js` and generate the token to store in cookies using clientid of that registered app (this has CRM access scope defined) like @AnkUser mentioned.

While calling web api, you have to pass the `Bearer Token` in header to pass through. Whenever this token expires, you have refresh the token every time.

[Read more](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/johntowgood/2018/02/12/dynamics-365-online-authenticate-with-user-credentials)